# Spring Batch - Filewriter Append Custom Date to File Name

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am new to Spring batch and trying to append custom date(not today date) to output file. I could find samples to get job parameters & job execution context in file writer step. But could not find solution for my scenario. Could someone help on this.
Given:
`<bean id="abstractFileWriter"  class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" abstract="true">
        <property name="resource" value="file:\target\HelloWorld.{MMDDYYYY}.txt"/>
        <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true" />

    </bean>`

Above file writer is parent for several steps which append data to same file.

Expected output is:
If {MMDDYYYY} is set to 01152016 then final output file name should be HelloWord.01152016.txt.

If we need to pass resource by reference instead of value please share how.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what if you remove the following line:

```
<property name="resource" value="file:\target\HelloWorld.{MMDDYYYY}.txt"/>
```

and then [setResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemWriter.html#setResource-org.springframework.core.io.Resource-) in the code. That way you can name it whatever you like in the code.

```
String myPath = "/Users/myName/blahblahblah_" + myDate + ".txt";
Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(myPath);
abstractFileWriter.setResource(resource);
```

I don't have a class or method.  I wrote this based on the config you provided and the documentation.  If I were to write a method for this I might write something like the following - however there are unknowns like what type of objects are you passing in and are you adding converters?

```
@Autowired
private abstractFileWriter;

public <T> void writeFile(List<T> itemList, String fileName, Date date) throws Exception{
  JavaConfigApplicationContext context = new JavaConfigApplicationContext(...);
  FlatFileItemWriter writer = context.getBean(FlatFileItemWriter.class, "abstractFileWriter");
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy");
  String stringDate = sdf.format(date);
  fileName = fileName + stringDate + ".txt";
  Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(fileName);
  writer.setResource(resource);
  writer.write(itemList);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Neal. I also found alternative way to get this done. Created util class and method to return day based on business logic. Could you post entire class and method.